Blazor Service does not get injected with bUnit
I have a problem with my .NET 8 Blazor bUnit Tests, where I try to get the services injected with the Services.AddSingleton<>() command, because I have an inject @inject CartService CartService, that causes an error, if I try to run the tests without (see bUnit Website as reference).
But it still is not working and throwing an error, that Services does not have a method called AddSingleton(). Does anybody have an idea, what I can do here?
public void ItemsAreShowedOnOverview() 
{
    Services.AddSingleton<CartService>(new CartService());
    using var ctx = new TestContext();
    var cutOverview = ctx.RenderComponent<Overview>();
    cutOverview.Find("p").MarkupMatches("<p>Taktiles Messgerät</p>");
}

I tried to run without the Services.AddSingleton<>() but it will not work an throw an error, that the service is not registered.

Did you forget to add a using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection clause? AddSingleton is an extension method

Yeah that is mentioned in the documentation, too. But even with the using it still does not work.

I was able to solve the problem by using ctx.Services.AddSingleton<CartService>()
